# Encapsulating layouts in a published Android library

Tags: android

I want to release an SDK that contains my activity with its own layout.
However, I don't want to publish my source code - just my reusable components.

It seems that I can't create a JAR, because I want to create XML layouts for my activities and also possibly add drawables, etc.
A library project is compiled only when the main project is compiled, so that doesn't hide my source code too.

So how would you do this? Is there a stable workaround for putting your resource XMLs inside a JAR and then extracting them in runtime? Or something more elegant?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make an Android Library Project if you want a re-usable component that includes Android-specific features rather than just Java, as you've found. As you've said this doesn't hide source code -- my only suggestion is perhaps it would be possible to combine a library project with a JAR of your code.

Comment: No -- I'm not sure anyone ever envisioned protecting the layout XML files. I don't think layout XML will ever contain code complicated enough to make it worth hiding. There's no business logic in the XML, and it's very limited as to what you can do. Some might even argue that layout files are so simplistic and the combinations so limited that they aren't even copyrightable (if you strip out the comments, a la Google).

Comment: Well, this question is more appropriate to the customer who requests this SDK... For now, I will stick with finding a good way to encapsulate it.
"Completely impossible" is an acceptable answer too, as long as this answer is provable.

Comment: I understand when it's a feature a client requests you have to do your utmost to acquiesce. I think it probably is at this stage (though you could perhaps obfuscate it in some way). If you want to know if it's completely impossible to protect layout XML code I'd ask on the Android developers group and see if you can get an answer from a member of the Android team.